what can we say about the relation of chromatic number and clique number of $G$?
Let $G$ be a $2K_2$-free graph with $V(G)=A\cup B$ . Both $G[A]$ and $G[B]$ are perfect graphs. For each vertex $a\in A$, $B-N(a)$ is stable. For  each vertex $b\in B$, $A-N(b)$ is triangle-free. What can we say about the relation of chromatic number and clique number of $G$?
